# Одна команда на 2 разных контрола

Tags: wpf

Есть форма, на ней нужно выбрать 2 пути => 2 кнопки, которые открывают `OpenFileDialog`, а напротив них `ComboBox'ы`.

Можно ли использовав всего 1 команду, сделать так, что бы заполнялся определенный `ComboBox`?

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
   public RelayCommand<object> OpenFileDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _openFileDialogCommand ?? (
                  _openFileDialogCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(obj =>
                      {
                          var fd = new OpenFileDialog();
                          fd.ShowDialog();
                          ((TextBox)obj).Text = fd.FileName;
                      }
                  ));
        }
    }

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..." Padding="15" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding ElementName=uc,Path=Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tb}"/>
</Grid>
```

Но мне кажется, что это не правильно... Так же в WM не обновляются забинженные на эти ComboBox поля, хотя стоит 2-ух сторонняя привязка.

Comment: Как то странно у вас все в вопросе. **1.** Противоречия... Вы пишите `заполнялся определенный ComboBox` - какой? Я виду упоминания в тексте о нем, но в коде я его не вижу, я вижу лишь TextBox и Button, которые находятся в Grid; **2.** Исходя из первого, лично я вообще не понимаю вашу задачу, может добавите скрин того, что хотите с результатом необходимым?; **3.** `Так же в WM не обновляются забинженные на эти ComboBox поля` - опять, какие ComboBox и где код, который покажет нам реализованную привязку, VM и др данные?

Comment: Отображение диалога тоже ведь задача представления, поэтому, я считаю, что команду здесь выставлять не нужно - просто подписывайтесь на клик по кнопке и выводите диалог.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, т.е будет по 1 событию на каждую кнопку?

Comment: У вас же одна кнопка в контроле?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну это продолжение той серии вопросов, где вы посвистывали сделать PathBox. На форме у меня 2 PathBox. У каждого PathBox своя кнопка.

Comment: Ну дык подписка и показ диалога будут внутри контрола. А снаружи вы просто привязываетесь к выставленному свойству Text

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм... Надо попробовать.

Comment: Напишите ответ, если всё получилось.